# Extend Laravel Logging to Include Method

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm in Laravel 5.1, for reference.

I'm looking to extend the Log feature in such a way that running it from any point in the code (including in the built in vendor libraries) will also trigger an additional method of my choosing.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel fires an event named `illuminate.log` when logging the data. So your can listen to that event and can call your extra methods.

For example:

Add following code in your `boot()` method of class `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot()
{
    \Event::listen('illuminate.log', function ($level, $message, $context) {
        // call your extra functions
    });
}
```